# window.location.reload not consider hash in ie

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery

I tried to reload a page with ajax. The url contains a hash (ancor)

```
index.php?page=2&obj=3#lb
```

I tried to use location.reload() or windows.location.reload(true)

```
$(".reload").click(function(){

    var userid = $(this).attr('userid');

    $.post("testpost.php", {userid:userid}, function(data){

    //window.location.reload(true);
            location.reload();

    });
});
```

With FF, Chrome and Opera works perfectly, but with IE when the page is reloaded (even if in the url of the browser there is the hash), the ancor is not considered and the page is viewed from above. How could I solve this problem? Thanks

EDIT

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".reload").click(function(){

  var userid = $(this).attr('userid');

  $.post("testpost.php", {userid:userid}, function(data){

    location.reload();

    });
  });

 var hash, el;
 if(hash = location.hash.substring(1) && el = document.getElementById(hash)) {
    el.scrollIntoView(true);
 }

});
```

Comment: do you have a URL you can share so I can try it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using `location.hash.substring(1)` to get the id of your element, get it using `document.getElementById`, and then [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollIntoView) it:

```
document.getElementById(location.hash.substring(1)).scrollIntoView(true);
```

In your case, you want it to happen after reload, so you could use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hash, el;
    if((hash = location.hash.substring(1)) && (el = document.getElementById(hash))) {
        el.scrollIntoView(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: @PaoloRossi My code doesn't reload the page because it isn't a substitute of your code. To reload, use your current code

Comment: I tried to add your code after my reload click function, but I've an error. What's wrong? Please look my edit.

Comment: @PaoloRossi Sorry, I forgot some parentheses.